# JRuby thread safety and arrays

Tags: multithreading, jruby

The [official document about JRuby thread safety](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Concurrency-in-jruby) states:

> At least these classes are not considered thread-safe, and if you intend to mutate them concurrently with other operations you will want to introduce locking (e.g. with Mutex): String, Array, Hash, and any data structures derived from them.

What exactly is the consequence of this, in particular the statement that the **classes** themselves are not threadsafe? Does it mean that if I use some Array in one thread, and I use a completely different Array in a different thread, I get a possible concurrency problem? Or does it mean that if I monkeypatch the Array class in one thread, and I do the same in a different thread, I could get a problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that if I use some Array in one thread, and I use a completely different Array in a different thread, I get a possible concurrency problem?

No

> Or does it mean that if I monkeypatch the Array class in one thread, and I do the same in a different thread, I could get a problem?

That would be an issue but the guide is not about monkey-patching.

The problem is you can not get predictable behavior when an `Array` instance is shared between multiple threads.

To clarify further if you create an `Array` in one thread and than multiple threads simply read it that is okay. Issues arise when mutating an `Array` instance while other threads would read/write to the same instance.

Same applies for `Hash` and `String`.

Comment: Good to know. But I have expected that this applies to **all** classes, not just `Array`. It should be the same for instance for any `IO` or `Enumerable` or `Rational`. Whenever I share a variable between threads, I need to take care of race conditions.

Comment: I don't understand why we don't have a problem with Monkey Patching. Say I add a method to, for instance, `Object` in one thread, and I add a different implementation in a different thread. Isn't the code be supposed to be common accross threads? How can this be thread safe?

Comment: > Good to know. But I have expected that this applies to all classes, not just `Array`.

Depends on the classes actually - you could built them to be thread-safe by design. 
If you need smt ready to use you have *concurrent-ruby* gem and they have equivalents e.g. `Concurrent::Array` a thread-safe `Array`.

> I don't understand why we don't have a problem with Monkey Patching. 

I did not say you won't have but in general the guide you read was about using core built-in classes "the usual way". Patching a class in one thread while another uses it does work to some extent under JRuby.

Comment: _to some extent_ : Do you happen to know a site which defines exactly, what is safe and what is not? The ones I came across, were pretty fuzzy about this.